# map over every combination of lat/lon values and store in a matrix the distance

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to compute some distances for each combination of lat/lon values I have.

The first data frame looks like:

```
     lon   lat NOMVIAL               
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 
 1 -99.1  19.5 Tepozanes             
 2 -99.0  19.3 Bartolomé Díaz de León
 3 -99.2  19.3 Renato Leduc          
 4 -99.2  19.2 Cuautlalpan
```

The second data frame looks like:

```
    CVEGEO mean_lat mean_lon
     <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 90130143     19.2    -99.1
2 90130234     19.2    -99.0
3 90090300     19.2    -99.0
```

So I want to take each combination in `df2` and compute the distances for each row in `df1` and storing the results as a matrix. I can compute the distances for a single lat/lon value using:

```
df1 %>% 
  add_column(
    M_lat = -99.183203,
    M_long = 19.506582
) %>% 
  mutate(
    Distance = geosphere::distHaversine(cbind(lon, lat), cbind(M_lat, M_long))
  )
```

However, I would like to use `map` and store the results as a matrix, as below.

Expected output:

```
                 90020001 90030001 90040001 90040010 90040020

    
Tepozanes            999      111      ...      ...      ...
Renato Leduc
Samahil
...
Primera              ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
```

Where the column names come from the column `GVEGEO` column in the `df2` and the row names come from the column `NOMVIAL` in the `df1` data frame. The values being the distances computed.

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(lon = c(-99.12587729, -99.03630014, -99.16578649, 
-99.18373215, -99.21312146, -99.29082258, -99.19958018, -99.05745354, 
-99.09046923, -99.04686154), lat = c(19.543991, 19.2921902, 19.29272965, 
19.2346386, 19.29264198, 19.32628302, 19.29913009, 19.38650317, 
19.47120537, 19.31618134), NOMVIAL = c("Tepozanes", "Bartolomé Díaz de León", 
"Renato Leduc", "Cuautlalpan", "Samahil", "Ninguno", "Monte de Sueve", 
"Ninguno", "Rinoceronte", "Primera")), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df2 <- structure(list(CVEGEO = c(90130143L, 90130234L, 90090300L, 90130284L, 
90130290L), mean_lat = c(19.2256141377143, 19.2447500775758, 
19.209320585524, 19.2219817711111, 19.2405991752941), mean_lon = c(-99.143825052, 
-99.0409973439394, -98.9713545799563, -99.1172106433333, -99.1347260164706
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

EDIT:

To clarify, hopefully, a little more clearly.

I would like to take each row of `df2` and use this to compute the distances of all rows in `df1`.

Take row 1 in `df2`

```
 CVEGEO       mean_lat      mean_lon
90130143      19.22561      -99.14383
```

Take these values and compute the distance for all of the rows in `df1` - so for each of the 10 rows in `df1` I will have a distance computed based on this row in `df2`. Then move to row 2 of `df2` and do the same again...

So this matrix will have dimensions 5 columns and 10 rows.

Comment: I don't understand how these 2 data frames are connected. You would please explain more. And also when you iterate over every row of `df1` what values do you choose from the other data frame.

Comment: I added an edit to explain a little more the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution. You have to swap `mean_lon` and `mean_lat` columns in your second data frame as you will get an error while `lon` and `lat` are exchanged.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

map2(df4$lon, df4$lat, ~ df5 %>% 
       rowwise() %>%
       mutate(output = geosphere::distHaversine(c(.x, .y), c_across(mean_lon:mean_lat)))) %>%
  set_names(df4$NOMVIAL) %>%
  map(~ .x %>% 
        select(CVEGEO, output) %>% 
        pivot_wider(names_from = CVEGEO, values_from = output)) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  mutate(rowname = df4$NOMVIAL)

# A tibble: 10 x 6
   rowname                `90130143` `90130234` `90090300` `90130284` `90130290`
   <chr>                       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 Tepozanes                  35492.     34483.     40636.     35857.     33786.
 2 Bartolomé Díaz de León     13513.      5304.     11476.     11549.     11831.
 3 Renato Leduc                7820.     14159.     22444.      9385.      6658.
 4 Cuautlalpan                 4313.     15044.     22501.      7133.      5193.
 5 Samahil                    10426.     18857.     27048.     12785.     10071.
 6 Ninguno                    19083.     27775.     36007.     21625.     18974.
 7 Monte de Sueve             10065.     17730.     25985.     12194.      9429.
 8 Ninguno                    20078.     15874.     21699.     19361.     18158.
 9 Rinoceronte                27908.     25739.     31724.     27885.     26088.
10 Primera                    14334.      7976.     14299.     12830.     12491.
```